# Traversal through limited permutation

Tags: arrays, algorithm, recursion, permutation, traversal

I have an array of ints of size N, lets call it "limits" and a variable called sum. What i would like to do is, create every array possible which the sum of the array equals to variable "sum" and every `createdArray[x] <= limits[x]`.
For example:

```
limits = [2, 3, 4, 5]
sum = 5

[2, 3, 0, 0]
[2, 2, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 4, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 5]
.....
```

I don't need to actually create the array, I just would like to loop through every possible scenario.

```
int recurse(int index, int limit, int increment) {
    if(index < 0 || index >= N) return 0;
    int value = 0, nextSize = limits[index + 1];

    if(checked[index][limit][increment] == -1) {
        for(int i = limit; i >= 0; i--) {
            int need = increment + limit - i, min = std::min(need, nextSize);

            value = std::max(value, getValue(index, i) + recurse(index + 1, min, need - min));
        }

        checked[index][limit][increment] = value;
        return value;
    }

    return checked[index][limit][increment];
}

int min = std::min(sum, limits[0]);

recurse(0, min, sum - min)
```

Comment: If you know how to enumerate permutations in general, you should be able to check the satisfiability of your constraints (limits, sum) as you move along, rejecting the prefixes that can't lead to a solution.

Comment: Well I can somewhat make it work, but when the array size, sums and limits get bigger, my code just halts and doesnt produce an output. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong. A code example would be an awesome jest. Thanks.

Comment: Post what you have now.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/r6Lx9nrq

Comment: I pulled your code over.

Comment: The code works, but it doesn't limit the calls made to itself, so it just keeps trying every possible scenario multiple times. Since it does have caching, it goes a pretty long way, but when the numbers get bigger, it just cant make it.
I couldn't get my head around to how to make it so it won't deadlock the process.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that generates all possible arrays recursively.

```
// Does something with a generated vector.
void process(const std::vector<int>& values) {
    for (int elem : values) {
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// Generates all possible vectors recursively. values is the generated prefix
// of the vector, limits is the vector that represents the limits, remaining_sum
// is the sum that the remainging elements must have and max_suffix_sum is
// the maximum sum achievable using the remaining elements according to the
// specified limits.
void generate(std::vector<int> values, const std::vector<int>& limits, 
        int remaining_sum, int max_suffix_sum) {
    if (values.size() == limits.size() && remaining_sum == 0) {
        process(values);
    } else if (max_suffix_sum >= remaining_sum) {
        int cur_pos = values.size();
        values.push_back(0);
        for (int curr = 0; curr <= std::min(remaining_sum, limits[cur_pos]); 
                curr++) {
            values.back() = curr;
            generate(values, limits, remaining_sum - curr, 
                    max_suffix_sum - limits[cur_pos]);
        }
    }    
}

...

generate(std::vector<int>(), limits, sum, 
        std::accumulate(limits.begin(), limits.end(), 0));
```

It is efficient because it avoids visiting branches that do not lead to a valid array.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out Geek Viewpoint. They actually have it solved and explained: http://www.geekviewpoint.com/java/bitwise/sum_of_tuple. The name of the algorithm is Sum of Tuple. They provide the answer in Java. But you can easily port it to another language.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a possible approach. We could find all the values that a single createdArray[x] can take and the ways to get each value, and then all the values that a pair could take and then continue from there. This could solve for the number of solutions in a relatively straightforward manner.
To keep track of the actual solutions you would just have to create a data structure to hold each of the "solution fragments".
For example createdArray[0] can be 0,1, or 2 and createdArray[1] can be 0,1,2, or 3. Therefore createdArray[0:1] can have the value 0 one way (the number of ways to get zero in createdArray[0] times the number of ways to get zero in createdArray[1] and it could achieve this value by any combination of ways to get zero on the left and zero on the right. We only need to keep track of values up until sum.

Full example:
    limits = [2,3,4,5]
    sum = 5

```
createdArray[0] = 0: (0), 1: (1), 2: (2)  
createdArray[1] = 0: (0), 1: (1), 2: (2), 3:(3)  
createdArray[2] = 0: (0), 1: (1), 2: (2), 3:(3), 4: (4)  
createdArray[3] = 0: (0), 1: (1), 2: (2), 3:(3), 4: (4), 5:(5)

createdArray[0:1] = 0: (0,0), 1: (1,0)(0,1), 2: (2,0)(1,1)(0,2), 3:(2,1)(1,2)(0,3), 4: (2,2)(1,3), 5:(2,3)
createdArray[2:3] = 0: (0,0), 1: (1,0)(0,1), 2: (2,0)(1,1)(0,2), 3:(3,0)(2,1)(1,2)(0,3), 4: (4,0)(3,1)(2,2)(1,3)(0,4), 5:(4,1)(3,2)(2,3)(1,4)(0,5)

createdArray[0:3] = ... 5: (0,0,4,1)(0,0,3,2)(0,0,2,3)(0,0,1,4)(0,0,0,5)(1,0,4,0)(1,0,3,1)(2,2)(1,3)(0,4)(4,0)(3,1)(2,2)(1,3)(0,4)...
```